My new particles are moving in the wrong direction
I have been working with the particles, I created the first ones and everything worked normally, but now, when I create a new system of particles, it seems that the new ones follow the old ones, but they are not linked to the curve, I don't know what's happening, because even creating a quick smoke the same thing happens.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Did you set the Field Weights collection properly (or leave it blank)?

@james_t I just modified the gravity. It seems to be more of a scene problem, because, if I transfer both particles to a new file everything works normally

Sometimes, blender wants us to go bald by ripping our hair out in frustration ;-)

It looks like a Cache problem to me (especially if same behavior occurs with other simulations). Did you give an explicit cache name or is it still blank ? Did you enable Disk Cache ?
